# Flutter CustomScrollView widgets are blinking on scroll

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have CustomScrollView inside it i have several Widgets, widgets item is blinking when im scrolling down   Code :

```dart
//Start of main widget 
Widget _buildSliverListItem() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
           FastAccessWidget(), // Use const for static widgets
           SizedBox(height: 20),
           LastPaymentsList(), // Use const for static widgets
           SizedBox(height: 20),
           CategoryListWidget(mainForm: true), // Use const for static widgets
           SizedBox(height: 20),
          //const CardList(), // Use const for static widgets
           SizedBox(height: 20),
           FavoriteList(), // Use const for static widgets
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 120,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  } 
// End of main Widget
```

My  CustomScrollView SliverList here :

```
 SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        ( ctx, int index) {
                      print(screenWidht);
                      if (index == 0) {
                        return _buildSliverListItem();
                      }
                    },
                    childCount: 1, // Set the number of items in the SliverList
                  ),
                ),
```

Please Help. to fix it